# angular-bootstrap-calendar : Add all weekends as event

Tags: angularjs, date, calendar, momentjs, angular-bootstrap

I want to Make common event in every Saturday and Sunday in [angular-bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar). Its possible to make an event in very first day of all months by this event

```
{
  title: 'Start of month',
  color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.important,
  startsAt:  moment().startOf('month').toDate(),
  endsAt: moment().startOf('month').toDate(),
  recursOn: 'month',
  draggable: true,
  resizable: true,
  actions: actions , 
  allDay: true 
}
```

But I Can't figure out how to add a event for every weekends.